# Spring Integration Gateway Inner Bean Definition

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-integration

I am in the process of upgrading:

- Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE => 4.0.6.RELEASE
- Spring Integration 2.1.0.RELEASE => 4.0.3.RELEASE

And am noticing some incompatibilities with the XML configuration of gateways as inner beans.

Before the upgrade, something like this was fine:

```
<bean id="eventPublisher" class="com.blorp.EventPublisher">
    <constructor-arg>
           <int:gateway default-request-channel="eventPublishingChannel"
                         default-reply-timeout="10000"
                         service-interface="com.blorp.messaging.Sender">
                <int:method name="send" />
            </int:gateway>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>


<int:channel id="eventPublishingChannel" />
```

After performing the aforementioned upgrade, when an event is actually sent at runtime an exception is thrown because the request channel has not been set:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: send is not supported, because no request channel has been configured
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385) ~[spring-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:197) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:344) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:304) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:295) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.send(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.blorp.DefaultEventPublisher.publish(DefaultEventPublisher.java:29) ~[blorp-0.54.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
...
```

When I step through with the debugger, the `MessageGatewaySupport.requestChannel` property is indeed `null` even though the configuration specifies it.

The workaround is to not configure the gateway as an inner bean. The snippet below runs fine:

```
<int:gateway id="sender" default-request-channel="eventPublishingChannel"
                         default-reply-timeout="10000"
                         service-interface="com.blorp.messaging.Sender">
    <int:method name="send" />
</int:gateway>

<bean id="eventPublisher" class="com.blorp.EventPublisher">
    <constructor-arg ref="sender" />
</bean>
```

I am curious why the former doesn't work after the upgrade. Is it some issue creating the proxy? Is it a bug? I haven't been able to find an issue for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's true, because here you try to configure `<gateway>` as nested element.

Since Spring Integration 3.0 it is possoble only in the `<chain>` definition.

The root of cause is here (`GatewayParser`):

```
boolean isNested = parserContext.isNested();
...
gatewayAttributes.put("defaultRequestChannel", element.getAttribute(isNested ? "request-channel" : "default-request-channel"));
```

For any other cases you really have to configure `<gateway>` as root component and use its `id` for injection to other beans.

It's just a simple cost of migration: other cases may not be so simple: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki

From other side I find you `nested` solution isn't so useful for integration as it is presented by `Gateway` pattern definition.

I'm really sure that some day you decide to use the same gateway interface from another service.

Don't try to treat framework in this case: it's just an API with wich we should follow, as we have to provide an object of concrete type as parameter to the existing methods of some Java core class.

Comment: I had seen the migration tips link but didn't find anything about this there or in searches, thanks for pointing out the GatewayParser. I'm hoping not to find other runtime surprises =)